# Streamwriter write new lines in textfile

Tags: c#

I need the StreamWriter to write a new single line in my textfile, when I write this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\Inlägg.txt"))
{                
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);              
}
```

It overwrites the previously written line in the textfile

To summarize: I need the streamwriter to write a new line **and not** overwrite what was written in the textfile earlier.

There are no error messages, I only need to change the writing mechanics

Comment: StreamWriter has an [overload for its constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) that allows you to specify Append operations on an existing file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do this in order to append to the file rather than overwrite. It's the `true` after your txt file that does this.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\Inlägg.txt"), true))
{                
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);              
}
```

Comment: Your brackets are slightly out of place - should be: `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\Inlägg.txt", true))`

Comment: Would be helpful to make `true` argument as named

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the following code:

#### Pre-C# 8

```
using (var sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\Inlägg.txt"))
{ 
    sw.WriteLine();
}
```

#### C# 8

```
using var sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\Inlägg.txt");
sw.WriteLine();
```

#### UPDATE

A shorter way :)

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\Inlägg.txt", "text");
```